# Examples of complex conversion between bases

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, base64

Question about converting from various bases/

Convert 0b11010111 to hexadecimal & decimal (I know you do 16**7 + 16**6 + 16**4... but what does the b stand for?)

Convert 0xA6 to binary & decimal (confused about the B and how to convert)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not about helping you convert manually between bases (explaining your maths), but I'll post some code in Python that does it for you since you tagged it.

Comment: **b**inary and he**x**adecimal. `0xA6` means 6 16**0s and A (10) 16**1s, i.e. 166

Comment: You changed the question.  Now the answers look silly.

Comment: Rolled back the last edit so that the question relates to the answers posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some conversions:

```
>>> bin(12)             # Binary is base 2 where switches are either on or off.
'0b1100'
>>> hex(0b1100)         # Hexadecimal is base 16, which is two to the fourth power.
'0xc'
>>> int(0b1100)         # Integer is of course base 10.
12
>>> int(0xa6)
166
>>> bin(0xa6)
'0b10100110'
>>>
```